# Webpack bundle splitting produces empty bundle.js

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, webpack

I am trying to keep my css (compiled from sass) and my js separated by creating two entry points and using the ExtractTextPlugin but for some reason I end up with an empty bundle.js (except for the manifest js code) and a correct style.css file. I am sure this has to do with how I configured my webpack.config.js, but I just can't figure out what I am doing wrong here...

```
const path = require('path')
const webpack = require('webpack')
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin')

/**
 * Default webpack configuration for development
 */
const config = {
  devtool: 'source-map',
  entry: {
    app: path.resolve(__dirname, 'resources/js/app.js'),
    style: path.resolve(__dirname, 'resources/sass/style.scss')
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/scripts'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel',
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015', 'react']
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css?minimize!resolve-url!sass?sourceMap'),
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'resources/sass')
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
        loader: 'url'
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin('../css/[name].css'),
  ],
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './public',
    colors: true,
    historyApiFallback: true,
    inline: true
  }
}

/**
 * If bundling for production, optimize output
 */
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  config.plugins.push(
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({comments: false}),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify('production')}
    })
  )
}

module.exports = config
```

And the output of running webpack:

[webpack console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUsRY.png)

When I comment out everything to do with the sass/css the resulting bundle.js looks fine. Also tried with just a simple css source file, but this gives the same empty result. Perhaps I need to use the CommonsChunkPlugin somehow? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: first - get rid of this `style: path.resolve(__dirname, 'resources/sass/style.scss')`  second  - `new ExtractTextPlugin('../css/[name].css', {allChunks: true})`, third - include a `link` tag on your page, and your styles should be here.

Comment: Doens't work unfortunately. Yes, my bundle.js get created fine now, but there is no style.css being generated now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I was able to generate both the `bundle.js` and the `style.css` by changing

```
output: {
  path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/scripts'),
  filename: 'bundle.js'
}
```

to

```
output: {
  path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/scripts'),
  filename: '[name].js'
}
```

I do also now end up with a small `style.js` and `style.js.map` file (containing the webpack manifest I think).

Comment: The remaining `style.js` file is (I think) due to https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/1967.